# Finding integers $x$ and $y$ such that $633x + 255y = 6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

The first bit of the question asks to find the gcd of $633$ and $255$ which I did and found that it's $3$.

However, the next bit asks this:

Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $633x + 255y = 6$, or explain why none exist.

At first I thought that the integers do exist because $3$ divides $6$ but I'm not sure if this is the right approach to this question.

Would be great if anyone could clear this up for me, thanks.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this problem, we use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). The basic idea here is that we want to keep the numbers becoming smaller and smaller. For example, how many times can we subtract $633$ by $255$? The answer is $2$, so we get:
$$633\cdot 1+255\cdot -2=123$$
Now, how many times can we subtract $255$ by $123$? Twice, so we get:
$$(255\cdot 1)-2\cdot (633\cdot 1+255\cdot -2)=633\cdot -2+255\cdot 5=9$$
Now, how many times can we subtract $123$ by $9$? $13$ times, so we get:
$$(633\cdot 1+255\cdot -2)-13\cdot(633\cdot -2+255\cdot 5)=633\cdot 27+255\cdot -67=6$$

Thus, the answer is $x=27$ and $y=-67$.

Answer (score 0):

When $gcd$ of $633$ and $255$ is $3$, so we know that there is two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\times 633 +b\times 255=3$. Now, you just need to consider $2a$ and $2b$ as your solution.